# Create/Update a row depending on values of other columns in table in MySql

Tags: mysql

Following is my table schema, we are using mysql 5.7 version

```
     CREATE TABLE rule_reports (
  pkey int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  domain varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  rule_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  rule_type varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  log_time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  count int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pkey),
  KEY dwl (domain,rule_id,log_time)
)
```

I want to increment ***count*** column instead of new row in the table, if 
combination of values of ***domain,rule_id,rule_type*** already exists in the table row

Sample rows of table

```
+------+-------------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+-------------------------+----------
| pkey | email                   | domain  |    rule_id       |    rule_type     | log_time                | count
+------+-------------------------+---------+------------------+------------------+-------------------------+-----------
|    1 | user1@yopmail.com       | user1   | 566              | type1        | 2016-09-13 17:23:02.000 | 1
|    2 | user2@yopmail.com       | user2   | 567              | type2        | 2016-09-13 17:23:02.000 | 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Suppose if statement like below should not create a row because same values for domain,rule_id,rule_type already exists in table so I need a ***count*** column increment here

```
insert into rule_reports(domain,rule_id,rule_type,count) values('user1',566,'type1',1)
```

Statement like below should create a new row in table

```
insert into rule_reports(domain,rule_id,rule_type,count) values('user3',568,'type3',1)
```

Comment: Why is the log_time part of the key and not the rule_type? If there are two rows with the same combination of domain,rule_id,rule_type but from different log_times, which one do you increment?

Comment: @Mureinik I expected this question, I will include date range while doing update approx for 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique index on the columns involved, and the use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to increment the count if the record already exists.

```
ALTER TABLE rule_reports ADD UNIQUE unique_index(domain, rule_id, rule_type);

INSERT INTO rule_reports (domain, rule_id, rule_type, count)
VALUES ('user1', 566, 'type1', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1
```

Comment: I can't put unique index because the combination of columns is not unique.

Comment: `because same values for domain,rule_id,rule_type already exists in table` ... then what do you mean by this?

Comment: I want to update the count per daily for this combination. So I will have a row per day for this combination